# Extract filtered links from page with Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I am extracting a list of tags from a github release page which I then use to determine the link of the release file I need to download.

In a nutshell, I'm currently doing this:

```yaml
- name: Get tags
  uri:
    url: https://github.com/project/app/tags
    return_content: true
  register: tag_info
  until: tag_info is not failed
  retries: 10
  delay: 5

- name: Get latest tag
  set_fact:
    release: '{{ (tag_info.content | regex_search(''/project/app/releases/tag/.*'')).split(''"'') | first }}'

- name: Build download url
  set_fact:
    download_url: "https://github.com/project/app/releases/download/{{release}}/my-app.rpm"
```

This all works fine, but I notice that when the project releases a nightly or dev/edge build (which has something like `-nightly-xyz` or `-git-abcd`), then ansible (correctly) picks it up. This is fine, but I'd like to know if it's possible to filter out those so that ansible picks the tag that doesn't match "-nightly-xyz" "-git-abcd" -- i.e. prioritise a "stable" release above a dev/nightly release.

I've been hunting around for different questions on SO that might help me assemble the right regex, but could never get ansible to pick it correctly.

Does anyone know how to get Ansible to pick the correct tag, while filtering out specific substrings?

As an example to work with, try https://github.com/helm/helm/tags. This page has tags that also have `rc` and `dev` -- let's assume I don't want those, so the ansible play I write should pick `v3.11.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the releases and tags

```yaml
    - uri:
        url: 'https://github.com/{{ project }}/tags'
        return_content: true
      register: tag_info
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
    project: helm/helm
    regex: "/{{ project }}/releases/tag/.*"
    releases: "{{ tag_info.content|regex_findall(regex) }}"
    tags_all: "{{ releases|
                  map('split', '\"')|
                  map('first')|
                  map('basename')|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  tags_all:
  - v3.12.0-rc.1
  - v3.11.3
  - v3.11.2
  - v3.12.0-dev.1
  - v3.11.1
  - v3.11.0
  - v3.11.0-rc.2
  - v3.11.0-rc.1
  - v3.10.3
  - v3.10.2
```

Q: ***"I don't want rc and dev tags."***

A: There are more options. If you want to reject `rc` and `dev` tags exclusively select and remove them from the list

```yaml
  tags_dev: "{{ tags_all|select('search', 'dev') }}"
  tags_rc: "{{ tags_all|select('search', 'rc') }}"
  tags: "{{ tags_all|difference(tags_dev)|difference(tags_rc) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
tags:
  - v3.11.3
  - v3.11.2
  - v3.11.1
  - v3.11.0
  - v3.10.3
  - v3.10.2
```

If you want to reject also other flavors the expression below gives the same result

```yaml
  tags: "{{ tags_all|reject('regex', '^.*-.*$') }}"
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    
    project: helm/helm
    regex: "/{{ project }}/releases/tag/.*"
    releases: "{{ tag_info.content|regex_findall(regex) }}"
    tags_all: "{{ releases|
                  map('split', '\"')|
                  map('first')|
                  map('basename')|unique }}"
    tags1: "{{ tags_all|reject('regex', '^.*-.*$') }}"
    tags_dev: "{{ tags_all|select('search', 'dev') }}"
    tags_rc: "{{ tags_all|select('search', 'rc') }}"
    tags2: "{{ tags_all|difference(tags_dev)|difference(tags_rc) }}"

  tasks:

    - uri:
        url: 'https://github.com/{{ project }}/tags'
        return_content: true
      register: tag_info
    #- debug:
    #    var: tag_info
    - debug:
        var: releases
    - debug:
        var: tags_all
    - debug:
        var: tags_dev
    - debug:
        var: tags_rc

    - debug:
        var: tags1
    - debug:
        var: tags2
```